# Given 5 numbers, by only using addition multiplication and substraction check whether we can generate 42?

Tags: algorithm

Given five numbers between 1-52 check whether you can generate 42 by using operations addition, multiplication and subtraction. You can use these operations any number of times. 
I got this question during an online test and couldn't do it.

Comment: Is this any programmatic question or a simple logical question

Comment: Imagine a graph: Starting node is the zero, which is connected to other nodes via edges that represent an operation (add, multiply, subtract) and the second operant, leading to the result represented by a node. I'll leave out the difficulties of that approach to you, hope I haven't spoiled it four you. BTW: You can use e.g. xdot to display graphs.

Comment: Looks like someone is asking for a solution to his/her homework :-(

Comment: Everyone is either missing the fact that a) you can do operations multiple times, or that b) the algorithm must terminate. A graph that one continually searches through (breadth first or otherwise) is undecidable for numbers such as `9 18 27 36 45`. I can tell you based on a program I wrote that if a set of five numbers cannot sum to 42, all of the numbers are multiples of a specific number.

Comment: After rereading the question, I realize I've made the following assumptions: numbers can be used multiple times (not just operations), the five numbers are unique, and the five numbers are between 1 and 52 *inclusive*. `paxdiablo` made a reasonable assumption, though it makes the problem rather trivial :(.

Comment: @Lahiru were my assumptions correct? Can you use the numbers as many times as you want?

Comment: @Smith I think you can use numbers any number of times. This is one of the most confusing questions I have seen in online timed interview. Thanks. yes 5 numbers are unique this is set of number in a card deck and you pick 5 out of them and they are between 1-52.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each *number* is to be used once and once only, with only five numbers and three operations, you can quite easily do this with a brute force approach.

It will only have to check `5 * 3 * 4 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 2 * 3 * 1`, or about `10,000` potential solutions.

As proof-of-concept, here's a Python program for doing this:

```
import sys
import itertools

if len(sys.argv) != 6:
    print "Usage: testprog.py <num1> <num2> <num3> <num4> <num5>"
    sys.exit(1)

ops = ['+', '-', '*']
nums = []
for num in sys.argv[1:]:
    nums.append(num)

for p in itertools.permutations(nums,len(nums)):
    for op1 in ops:
        for op2 in ops:
            for op3 in ops:
                for op4 in ops:
                    expr = p[0] + op1 + p[1] + op2 + p[2] + op3 + p[3] + op4 + p[4]
                    result = eval(expr)
                    if result == 42:
                        print expr, '=', result
```

Running that shows the results for the numbers `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }`:

```
pax$ time python testprog.py 1 2 3 4 5
2*4*5-1+3 = 42
2*4*5+3-1 = 42
2*5*4-1+3 = 42
2*5*4+3-1 = 42
:
5*4*2-1+3 = 42
5*4*2+3-1 = 42

real    0m0.187s
user    0m0.093s
sys     0m0.077s
```

and you can see that it completes in about a fifth of a second (on my box).

Comment: there is no limitation like each number can only be used once or each operation is only once. Numbers are unique too.

Comment: @Lahiru, hence "assuming" being the first word of my answer. In any case, your _other_ comments seem to indicate you don't _know_ whether this is a limitation, so you should go back to clarify the requirements, just like in real life. Keep in mind interviewers often couldn't care less whether you can _solve_ the problem, they just want to see how you _handle_ the situation. It's almost _always_ advisable to ask questions clarifying what they want.

Comment: thank you so much, this was in an online test so there was no clue for me and there was nobody to clarify. I don't know how to solve such problems in 30 minutes and write code with tests.

Comment: @Lahiru: well, if there's no means to clarify requirements, you have to go with best effort based on the information you have. Or, after you've spent enough time in the industry, whatever's easiest to implement for you :-) In the real word, you would pose the query thus: "This is the way I think it should be done, please clarify if that's not the case. In the absence of a response, I'll proceed based on my assumptions".

Answer (score 0):

assumtions:

- any number may be used multiple times
- operations are done immediately (no operator precedence)

do a breadth first search over the graph

```
from collections import defaultdict

def add(lhs, rhs):
    return lhs+rhs

def sub(lhs, rhs):
    return lhs-rhs

def mul(lhs, rhs):
    return lhs*rhs

ops = [add, sub, mul]   #allowed operations

graph = { 0:["0"]}      #graph key is node(number); value is a list of shortest paths to this node 
numbers=[1,2,3]         #allowed numbers in operations
target=12               #target node(number) 
gv_edges=[]             #edges for optional graphviz output 

#breadth first search until target is met
while not target in graph:
    new_graph=defaultdict(list, graph)
    for key in graph:
        #inefficiently searches old nodes also
        for n in numbers:
            for op in ops:
                newkey = op(key, n)
                if newkey not in graph:
                    #not met in previous iterations, keep new edge
                    newvals = ["{} --{}({})--> {}".format(val, op.__name__, n, newkey) for val in new_graph[key]]
                    new_graph[newkey].extend(newvals)    
                    gv_edges.append('"{}" -> "{}" [label="{}({})"]'.format(key, newkey, op.__name__, n))
                else:
                    #already met in previous iterations (shorter paths), do not keep new
                    pass
    graph=dict(new_graph)


#print all solutions
print "Solutions:"
print
for val in graph[target]:
    print val
print
print

#print optional graphviz digraph
gv_digraph='digraph {{ rankdir=LR ranksep=2\n"{}" [color=green style=filled fillcolor=green]\n{}\n}}'.format(target,"\n".join(gv_edges))
print "Graphviz Digraph for paste into http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/"
print "do this for reasonable number of edges only"
print
print gv_digraph
```

results in the following solutions:

```
0 --add(1)--> 1 --add(3)--> 4 --mul(3)--> 12
0 --add(2)--> 2 --add(2)--> 4 --mul(3)--> 12
0 --add(2)--> 2 --mul(2)--> 4 --mul(3)--> 12
0 --add(3)--> 3 --add(1)--> 4 --mul(3)--> 12
0 --add(2)--> 2 --mul(3)--> 6 --mul(2)--> 12
0 --add(3)--> 3 --mul(2)--> 6 --mul(2)--> 12
0 --add(3)--> 3 --add(3)--> 6 --mul(2)--> 12
0 --add(3)--> 3 --mul(3)--> 9 --add(3)--> 12
```

the complete graph (only shortest paths!) for depth 3 looks like
[image]